# Chrome extension - Where to save big data

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I'm a developer of an extension with more than 15000 active users.
Many users ask for a sync feature.
Well, I have done some calculations and found out that each user has about 8 MB data to sync.
It is more than 100 GB.
Where they can be saved?
The extension is free and there is no way to monetize it to pay for a server.
The Google Drive does not allow to save into App Data from extensions.
Are there another ways to save user's data outside user's browser?
Google has no service to save data of its users?

Comment: I have already unlimitedStorage and save user's data in local storage. The key question is where to save data OUTSIDE the browser to sync.

Comment: Ah then it's off-topic here. I think you can find such services using google, there should be reviews etc. I know of https://mega.nz offering 50GB free.

Comment: the short answer is use Google Drive

Comment: As I have said you can't use AppData folder from an extension. You can use simple access but that is bad choice because files will be opened to user.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN save into Google Drive's appFolder from an extension. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata). It has a quite comprehensive RESTful API.

Comment: No you can't do that. I suggest you to try.

Comment: I've successfully done that with my extension: [LBTimer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nocdlcgkdeopogoldfeahdneobfaiggd/)

Comment: @holden321 I don't use Google API library (`gapi`) but directly use `XMLHttpRequest`s instead, following the [available documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/)

Comment: I tried but without success http://joxi.net/DmBN78lswDjkPm. I'm getting error The granted scopes do not allow use of the Application Data folder. Note the commented path. With that path code works. Obviously, something wrong with parameters. Can you share your unobfuscated code, please? Is it so secret?

Comment: @holden321 There are differences between Drive API v3 and v2 (read [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) carefully). For example, for the file's name, you use `name` in v3 but `title` in v2. Make sure you use the [correct scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth). The code is not secret nor obfuscated, it is minified.

Comment: Any minification is obfuscation. I found solution. "Thanks for your help."

Answer (score -1):

Why not just just use [Google Chrome's built in sync feature](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139) and use the [chrome.storage API to store, retrieve, and track changes to user data](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync)?

Comment: Because the sync.storage is too small. It's has just 100 KB maximum.

Comment: Use Firebase then https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start / https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/